# Update also the "wanted" version modules with npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it possible to update all the global modules to the latest version? Also the once wit hset a fixe wanted version?

Is there a config file for the wanted versions of the global node modules?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no built-in way of doing this with only npm.

But there is a npm package which does this : [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) where you can specify the global option (`-g`) to check if your globally installed packages can be updated. I'll let you check the options, it's really practical.